# Maintain one to many relationship

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

I want to make sure that I am maintaining a one-to-many relationship throughout a section of Oracle SQL code. The code is shown below:
This first section of SQL creates the view cont_ID_group by taking just one column, cont_id and grouping it so that its one ID per row.

The second view does the same with mix_id. The view AS_BUILT_DATA is the first example of whether or not a one-to-many relationship is being maintained. I am using the as_built_Groups view to hopefully create that relationship.

The final bit of code is the most important since it creates the final dataset before I map it in ArcGIS. Again I am trying to maintain the one-to-many relationship by relating both the DATABASE_PROJECT_MAPPABLE view and the AS_BUILT_DATA to the cont_ID_group view.

DATABASE_PROJECT_MAPPABLE and AS_BUILT_DATA have a many to many relationship.

```
create or replace view cont_ID_group as
select cont_id
from DATABASE_PROJECT_MAPPABLE
group by cont_id
;
create or replace view as_built_Groups as
select t.mix_id 
from SMGR.T_CONT_MIX_DSN t
group by t.mix_id
;
create or replace view AS_BUILT_DATA as
select d.cont_id,t.* 
from SMGR.T_SUPERPAVE t
inner join as_built_Groups s 
on t.mix_id = s.mix_id
inner join SMGR.T_CONT_MIX_DSN d
on d.mix_id = s.mix_id
;
select distinct t.*,
from DATABASE_PROJECT_MAPPABLE t inner join cont_ID_group i
on t.cont_id = i.cont_id inner join AS_BUILT_DATA s
on s.cont_id = i.cont_id
order by t.Corridor_RB,t.PROJECT_START,t.PROJECT_NUMBER
```

Comment: So....do you have a question?

Comment: Yes I would like to know whether I am keeping a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: ...one-to-many relationship between **which columns**? You *do* understand that we can't magically peer into your database and look at your data, right? Nor can we see any entity relationships between the tables that you're building your data off of.

Comment: Between the cont_id columns in the final select statement

Comment: Okay...why don't you do the requisite aggregation in your resulting data (after saving it into a table) and find out? **How do you expect us to magically be able to do this for you**???

Comment: Wait...your last `select` statement only takes things from one table...so it only has one of the `cont_id` columns from the various tables that you're working with. In that context, how does your question make any sense whatsoever?

Comment: I guess it doesn't. Have nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views do not enforce relationships. If you want to maintain (enforce) a one to many relationship, you should create a `PRIMARY KEY` on the "parent" table and then create a `FOREIGN KEY` on the child table, that references the primary key of the parent table,

Comment: Ya that's part of the problem. The final sql query will also become a view so that it can be regularly updated with new data and pulled into GIS for mapping. So doing create or replace view is the best option.

Comment: Im trying to create a dataset view that can be left alone and run from GIS by people who know nothing about SQL or programming. Not that im anything great.

Comment: Creating a PRIMARY KEY / FOREIGN KEY (PK/FK) relationship on the tables does not preclude you creating any views; they are not mutually exclusive.  But your original question was about maintaining those relationships. Moreover, having PK/FK in place can provide a performance optimization in some cases.

Comment: The two tables that create the third view SMGR.T_SUPERPAVE and SMGR.T_CONT_MIX_DSN have composite primary keys both of which are in another schema that I don't manage. The DATABASE_PROJECT_MAPPABLE is another view without any sort of key.

Comment: The "view" that you refer to, I assume is the intersection or bridge table between your two tables with the menu to many? If that is the case, then this "view" should actually be a table. Then you will create two PK/FK relationships from the bridge table

Comment: Yes I think what I need to do is make a junction table between DATABASE_PROJECT_MAPPABLE and AS_BUILT_DATA. The only way to relate SMGR.T_SUPERPAVE and SMGR.T_CONT_MIX_DSN  is through a very subtle many to many relationship.

Comment: It's not that subtle :). It's pretty much standard database design :)

Comment: Well thanks for the input. Ill give you the answer since it doesn't seem like much can be done for me. Enjoy the weekend!